# Can change camera's Device Parameters using Aravis github project

Tags: python, linux, flir, genicam, aravis

Code is provided below.

The line:
device.set_string_feature_value('PixelCoding', 'Raw')
is not working. It defaults pixelCoding to the default (Mono)

I tired putting the lines:
device.set_integer_feature_value('TLParamsLocked', 0)
device.set_integer_feature_value('TLParamsLocked', 1)
to see if this was not letting the parameters update, but that didnt work.

Let me know if you need more elaboration on anything.

link to project: https://github.com/AravisProject/aravis

```
import sys
import gi 
import numpy

gi.require_version('Aravis', '0.6')
from gi.repository import Aravis

Aravis.enable_interface("Fake")

try:
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        camera = Aravis.Camera.new(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        camera = Aravis.Camera.new(None)
except:
    print("No camera found")
    exit()

camera.set_region(0,0,512,640)
camera.set_frame_rate(30.0)

device = camera.get_device()
device.set_integer_feature_value('TLParamsLocked', 0)


device.set_string_feature_value('SensorGainMode', 'HighGainMode')
device.set_string_feature_value('TemperatureLinearMode', 'On')
device.set_string_feature_value('TemperatureLinearResolution', 'High')
device.set_string_feature_value('PixelFormat', 'MONO16')
print device.get_boolean_feature_value('TLParamsLocked')
device.set_string_feature_value('PixelCoding', 'Raw')

print("pixel coding")
print device.get_string_feature_value('PixelCoding')
print device.get_string_feature_value('PixelFormat')

payload = camera.get_payload()

[x,y,width,height] = camera.get_region()

print("Camera vendor : %s" %(camera.get_vendor_name()))
print("Camera model  : %s" %(camera.get_model_name()))
print("Camera id     : %s" %(camera.get_device_id()))
print("ROI           : %dx%d at %d,%d" %(width, height, x, y))
print("Payload       : %d" %(payload))
print("Pixel format  : %s" %(camera.get_pixel_format_as_string()))

stream = camera.create_stream(None, None)


for i in range(0,10):
    stream.push_buffer(Aravis.Buffer.new_allocate(payload))

print("Start acquisition")

camera.start_acquisition()

print("Acquisition")

for i in range(0,20):
    buffer = stream.pop_buffer()
    data = buffer.get_data()

    img_data = numpy.ndarray(buffer=data, dtype=numpy.uint16, shape=(camera.get_region()[3], camera.get_region()[2], 1))
    #print img_data[0]
    #numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", img_data, delimiter=",")
    if buffer:
        stream.push_buffer(buffer)

print("Stop acquisition")

camera.stop_acquisition()
device.set_integer_feature_value('TLParamsLocked', 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the Camera PixelCoding is not able to be modified by the user. Verified using GEV DEMO application